# MySQL Insert Into Table From Multiple Tables Using Separate SELECT Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named people_temp_1 that contains:

```
Name          Age          PersonID
John          25           1
Jane          32           2
Chris         47           3
```

And another named people_temp_2 that contains additional information that is linked by the PersonID in table1:

```
ID          Profession          Location
1           Web Developer       Texas
2           Graphic Designer    North Carolina
3           Sales               California
```

And I want to create a new table called people that "merges" the data from both tables. How I am doing this now is:

```
INSERT INTO people(name, age, profession, location)
SELECT people_temp_1.name AS name,
people_temp_2.age AS age,
(SELECT people_temp_2.profession FROM people_temp_2 WHERE people_temp_2.id = people_temp_1.personId) AS profession,
(SELECT people_temp_2.location FROM people_temp_2 WHERE people_temp_2.id = people_temp_1.personId) AS location
FROM people_temp_1
```

As you can see I am using multiple select queries in the insert into query in order to get data that is relevant via the personId. It seems a little dirty to be doing multiple select queries when I should somehow be able to query the people_temp_2 table once and use all of its columns, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Is there a better way to structure that insert into statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one of the basics of SQL - use [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). In your case it's better to use `outer join` so you won't miss people from `people_temp1` who don't have corresponding records in `people_temp2`:

```
insert into people(name, age, profession, location)
select
    p1.name,
    p1.age
    p2.profession,
    p2.location
from people_temp1 as p1
    left outer join people_temp2 as p2 on p2.id = p1.person_id
```

Comment: I went with this answer because of the suggestion of outer join. Although all answer appear to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use join syntax as below

```
INSERT INTO people(name, age, profession, location)
SELECT p1.namename,
p2.age,
p2.profession,
p2.location
FROM people_temp_1 p1
JOIN people_temp_2 p2 on p2.id = p1.personId
```

**[More information about joins on mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`.

```
INSERT INTO people(name, age, profession, location)
SELECT t1.name, t1.age, t2.profession, t2.location
FROM people_temp_1 t1
INNER JOIN people_temp_2 t2
ON t1.personid = t2.id
```